# Complex Concatenation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am having trouble concatenating while returning value.

```
return "<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-block btn-success' href='javascript:void(0)' 
onClick='chk()' >Verify By Support</a>"
```

What i want to do is put a block of code in onclick chk function.

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>fieldwork/verify_troubleshoot_support/oObj.aData[1]
/oObj.aData[15]
```

what i have tried so far is

```
return "<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-block btn-success' href='javascript:void(0)' 
onClick='chk("+<?php echo base_url()?>fieldwork"+/"+verify_troubleshoot_support+"/"+Obj.aData[1]+"/"+Obj.aData[15]+")' >Verify By Support</a>"
```

but i am getting error

Comment: `but i am getting error`.. What is the error?

Comment: you made a typo after `fieldwork` need to be `fieldwork+"/"+`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in console

Comment: is the concatenation correct??

Comment: Remove the `+` before `<?php` - your PHP code can echo directly into the JS, you don't have to do it as a JS concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Change `fieldwork"+/"` to `fieldwork+"/"`

Also it would be better if you assign it to a `variabale` first for simplicity.

**UPDATED**

```
var data = "<?php echo base_url()?>fieldwork/"+verify_troubleshoot_support+"/"+Obj.aData[1]+"/"+Obj.aData[15];

return "<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-block btn-success' href='javascript:void(0)' 
onClick='chk(data)' >Verify By Support</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
return "<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-block btn-success' href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='chk("+<?php echo base_url()?>fieldwork"+/"+verify_troubleshoot_support+"/"+Obj.aData[1]+"/"+Obj.aData[15]+")' >Verify By Support</a>"
```

to:

```
return "<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-block btn-success' href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='chk("+<?php echo base_url()?>fieldwork+"/"+verify_troubleshoot_support+"/"+Obj.aData[1]+"/"+Obj.aData[15]+")'>Verify By Support</a>"
```

Comment: still Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :